# Thread problem c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, program-entry-point

I have 2  Threads. 
In my worker thread (not main Thread) I create a picturebox array and sometimes I need to add a new picturebox to the main form, but I don't have access to this form. I read somewhere that I need to use invoke method but I only know how to update one picturebox or a label. 
I don't know how to do this with this bit of code:

```
food[x].Location = new Point(100,100);
food[x].Size = new Size(10,10);
food[x].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
food[x].ImageLocation = "food.png";
this.Controls.Add(food[x]);
food[x].BringToFront;
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You probably shouldn't have multiple threads.

Comment: SLaks is right. This sounds like a disaster waiting to happen. It is very difficult to get UI programming right when two threads are trying to access the same UI elements. Usually the way this works is that *only the UI thread is allowed to talk to the UI elements*. If you have worker threads that need to talk to the UI, then you need to set up some way for the worker thread to talk to the UI thread, and then the UI thread passes the message along to the UI object.

Comment: du you habe a code example or a tutorial?

Comment: put the (create it) PictureBox in UI thread (probably the "main" thread" you are talking about), and then call Dispatcher.BeginInvoke from the other thread for manipulating all the objects that are in the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

In WinForms, you should only have one UI thread, and only that thread should create or use UI components.

Use a `BackgroundWorker` to load the images, if necessary, and leave the `PictureBox` creation to the UI thread on the `BackgroundWorker`'s completion.

Answer (score 1):

Background threads cannot access GUI controls owned by the main thread.

If you want to communicate information to the GUI, the thread must communicate to the main thread, which then manipulates the GUI control.

BackgroundWorker threads provide ways to signal the main thread. See http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use WPF i recommend to use SynchronazationContext to save the main thread, all other thread will use this instance of SynchronazationContext to access the main thread (UI). You use it in this manner (Note: i generated a method that do this and all other methods will access this method to update the UI):

```
SynchronazationContext ctx = null;
void DoSomething()
{
    ctx = SynchronazationContext.Current;
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
    t.Start();
}

//This method run in separate Threads
void ThreadProc()
{
    //Some algorithm here

    SendOrPostCallback callBack  = new SendOrPostCallback(UpdatePic);
    ctx.Post(callBack, String.Format("Put here the pic path");
}
void UpdatePic(string _text)
{  
    //This method run under the main method
   //In this method you should update the pic
}
```

In .NET 5.0 you can call this complicated functions by mark the method as async and write 'await' when you call the synchronous method - that make the synchronous method as asynchronous method and update the UI with the main thread.

Comment: So i copy this code and than i add my code to add a picture box in the updatepix methode? and also i put the path(food.png) in the thread proc method?
thank for all the help. i will try it tomorrow we have here 3am ;)

Comment: Thats right, thats exactly what should you do, in this way you access the main thread from other thread.. by the way i note right now bug in my example code, i fix it shortly, the bug is that i called to UpdatePic method from the DoSomething method, please try to run it now without the bug (i erased it).

Comment: So now i have a problem. i got a error message. the Extension Methods have not to be in a static class. sorry i get only german erorrs i hope you know what i mean.
so thats the problem.'
additional you forgot a" ( " at   ctx.Post(callBack, String.Format("Put here the pic path");

Comment: Your code looks fine, i think the exception is because your class is static class, try to run this code with instantiate class (remove the static on the declaration class). Keep response if you have got more problems.

Comment: so now i have a new error: No overload for 'method' matches delegate 'delegate'

at this line: SendOrPostCallback callBack = new SendOrPostCallback(UpdatePic);